# 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for

Tags: c#

Ошибки:

```
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Parents'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Mother'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Father'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Similarity'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'SkinSimilarity'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Gender'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Hair'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Color'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'HighlightColor'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'EyebrowColor'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'BeardColor'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'EyeColor'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'BlushColor'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'LipstickColor'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'ChestHairColor'
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Features'
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Appearance'
The name 'Value' is bound to a method and cannot be used like a property
'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' does not contain a definition for 'Opacity'
```

Код:

```cs
public static void LoadCharacter(Player player, string character_name)
{
    if (CustomPlayerData.ContainsKey(player)) CustomPlayerData.Remove(player);

    using (MySqlConnection Mainpipeline = new MySqlConnection(Main.myConnectionString))
    {
        Mainpipeline.Open();
        MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE `name` = '" + character_name + "' LIMIT 1;", Mainpipeline);

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader())
        {
            string data2txt = string.Empty;
            string datatxt = string.Empty;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var character = API.Shared.FromJson(reader.GetString("char"));

                CustomPlayerData.Add(player, new PlayerCustomization());

                CustomPlayerData[player].Parents.Mother = (byte)character.Parents.Mother;
                CustomPlayerData[player].Parents.Father = (byte)character.Parents.Father;
                CustomPlayerData[player].Parents.Similarity = (float)character.Parents.Similarity;
                CustomPlayerData[player].Parents.SkinSimilarity = (float)character.Parents.SkinSimilarity;
                CustomPlayerData[player].Gender = character.Gender;

                CustomPlayerData[player].Hair.Hair = character.Hair.Hair;
                CustomPlayerData[player].Hair.Color = character.Hair.Color;
                CustomPlayerData[player].Hair.HighlightColor = character.Hair.HighlightColor;

                CustomPlayerData[player].EyebrowColor = character.EyebrowColor;
                CustomPlayerData[player].BeardColor = character.BeardColor;
                CustomPlayerData[player].EyeColor = character.EyeColor;
                CustomPlayerData[player].BlushColor = character.BlushColor;
                CustomPlayerData[player].LipstickColor = character.LipstickColor;
                CustomPlayerData[player].ChestHairColor = character.ChestHairColor;

                CustomPlayerData[player].ChestHairColor = character.ChestHairColor;

                for (int i = 0; i < CustomPlayerData[player].Features.Length; i++) CustomPlayerData[player].Features[i] = character.Features[i];

                for (int i = 0; i < CustomPlayerData[player].Appearance.Length; i++)
                {
                    CustomPlayerData[player].Appearance[i].Value = (byte)character.Appearance[i].Value;
                    CustomPlayerData[player].Appearance[i].Color = (byte)character.Appearance[i].Color;
                    CustomPlayerData[player].Appearance[i].Opacity = character.Appearance[i].Opacity;
                }

                ApplyCharacter(player);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    CustomPlayerData.Add(player, new PlayerCustomization());
    ApplyCharacter(player);
}
```

Comment: думаю в вопрос не помешало бы добавить пример JSON

Comment: Здесь же вроде, очевидно, не? Строка `var character = API.Shared.FromJson(reader.GetString("char"));`отдает вам не класс, а объект `JObject` с котором работают примерно так: `character["SomeJsonKey"];`, а вы пытаетесь работать с ним, как с неким объектом, который должен в себе вдруг содержпть цвет, родителей персонажа и так далее. Делайте тогда это класс, делайте десериализацию в него и будет вам счастье, а сейчас вы попросту требуете то, чего нет.

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет приведение `JObject` к типу `dynamic`.